# Proof identity for any function: $F(A) \cap B = F(A \cap F^{-1}(B))$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

Let any number $y\in(f(A))\cap B$. We want to show that $y \in f(A \cap f^{-1}(B))$. Then $X \in A$ and $y \in B$. What should I do next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prove that the given two sets contains each other:

1. For $f(A)\cap B\ \subseteq\ f(A\cap f^{-1}(B))$, take an arbitrary element $y$ from $f(A)\cap B$. This means that $y\in f(A)$ and $y\in B$, so that $y\in B$ and there is an $x\in A$ such that $f(x)=y$. Now conclude that $x\in A\cap f^{-1}(B)$ and from here, $f(x)\in f(A\cap f^{-1}(B))$.
2. Show that $f(A\cap f^{-1}(B))\ \subseteq\ f(A)\cap B$ similarly.